# КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ЧТОБЫ ЭТИ ДВЕ СТРОКИ ПОЯВЛЯЛИСЬ СРАЗУ, А НЕ ПО ОЧЕРЁДНО?

Tags: python

```
x = int(input("ВЕДИ ПЕРВОЕ ЧИСЛО"))

y = int(input("ВЕДИ ВТОРОЕ ЧИСЛО"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Не эксперт, но думаю так:

```
print("Введи первое число")
print("Введи второе число")
oneNumber = int(input(""))
twoNumber = int(input(""))
```

В следующий раз попытайтесь скрыть свои эмоции и не писать текст капсом

Answer (score 1):

ну можно и кардинально по другому:

```
x, y = map(int, input("ВЕДИТЕ ДВА ЧИСЛА (через пробел)").split())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое